# Getting Invalid data extension reference. While using first name personalization token

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, personalization

I've used email studio to develop emails but have never had to really use AMPScript or personalization tokens.

I am trying to create an email that uses a first name token but when trying to send a test preview I am getting this error:

Invalid data extension reference. No data extension was found with the specified name Data Extension Name: PersonalizationDE__ Client ID: 00000000 Parameter Name: customObjectName

The token I am trying to use is:

```
Hi First Name, 
%%[IF Empty([FIRSTNAME]) THEN]%%%%[ELSE]%%Hi %%=ProperCase(FIRSTNAME)=%%, %%[ENDIF]%%
```

What is causing this error?

Any help would greatly be appreciated! I have tried searching a bunch of other threads but have not found one with this issue.

Comment: It seems you have another code block that will do a lookup to a Data Extension that it doesn't exist in the Business Unit. Try check if the DE is existing in the BU or not.